# On going to the profile page, the 'profile_pic' has no file associated with it, value error shows up

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

When I log in a new user this error that no files are associated with the 'profile_pic' shows up and i've set the profile_pics value to default as well but i don't know the issue any more

this is models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null= True , blank = True, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default = "static/profileimages/msi.jpg", null = True, blank= True)
    first = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null= True)
    postal = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first
```

This is the views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import CreateUserForm, ProfileForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import *

def RegisterPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('Profile')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
                messages.success(request, 'Account created for ' + name)
                Profile.objects.create(
                    user = user,
                )
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/Login/')
        else:
            form = CreateUserForm()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'register.html', context)    

@login_required(login_url='Login')
def profile(request):
    profile = request.user.profile
    form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

This is the template:

```
<div class="col-lg middle middle-profile-con">

        <div class="img-cir profile-img">
            <img src="{{request.user.profile.profile_pic.url}}" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" class="pro-img">

        </div>

        <form method='POST' action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="">
                <p class="my-name-pro">{{request.user.profile.first}}
                    <p>
                        <p class="my-email-id-pro">{{request.user.profile.email}} <br> {{form.profile_pic}}</p>

            </div>
```

I don't understand what's wrong in this

Answer (score 0):

In your models.py in the `profile_pic` field you are setting a default parameter to a static url, instead use `upload_to`, like this:

```
profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = "static/profileimages", null = True, blank= True)
```

Like that you are redirecting the image file to your static img folder.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Did not change anything, it still says the same thing

Comment: Are you able to see the image loaded in Django admin? Or in your static img folder?